# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame when using .loc[row_idx, col_idx] = value

Tags: pandas, numpy

I get this famous error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

But I did the following to avoid it:

```
df.loc[array == value, column] = new_value
```

Is `array == value` not a valid row_indexer? I think i've been using this extensively.

thanks for any insight!

Comment: The issue is probably further upstream and related to how `df` was created. For example `df = another_df[['col1', 'col2']]` may return a view. Use `df = another_df[['col1', 'col2']].copy()` to make sure it's a new copy

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks, I thought it may be because it's a view, I don't want to use copy but I never created a new variable, always inplace operations. So I'm not creating a view to my knowledge anywhere.

Comment: @CodeDifferent yes, I just double checked, this is the original df, it's never been copied or being copied to. Whenever referenced I used to_numpy() but then even if, the view would be another_df and not original_df

Comment: The problem isn't in this line of code, and you have't provided any other code, so I don't know what to tell you.